# React.js. Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs, coffeescript, snap.svg

I want to add SVG in React component. I use CoffeeScript without JSX:

```
svg viewbox: '0 0 800 600',
   path 
      id: 'top'
      d: 'M300,220 C300,220 520,220 540,220 C740,220 640,540'
```

and I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M300,220 C300,220 520,220 540,220 C740,220 640,540"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems reasonable, [a cubic bezier defined using the C command must have 6 values following it](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands) and yet your final one has only 4.